# Creating a function $f$ to measure "distance" in $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have two numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{ > 0}$.

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. if $a = b$, $f(a, b) = 0$;
2. $f(a, b) \in [0, 1]$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$;
3. $f$ is monotonically increasing with respect to $|a - b|$ (i.e., as $|a - b|$ increases, $f$ is increasing)?

I was considering using the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit#Definition) (i.e., $$f(a, b) = \dfrac{\exp(|a-b|)}{1+\exp(|a-b|)}$$)
but if $a = b$, then $f(a, b) = 1/2$. Perhaps the most difficult part is trying to bound this in $[0, 1]$, for which I only know of the probit and logit transformations.

This is not a homework problem. Triangle inequality is a plus, but is not necessary.

Comment: How about trying to use $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(|a-b|)$?  More interesting is trying to find one that satisfies the triangle inequality as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the usual thing to do here would be to use $$f(a,b) = \frac{\lvert a - b\rvert}{1 + \lvert a - b \rvert}.$$ This defines a bounded metric on $\mathbb R$ which generates the same topology as the standard metric $d(a,b) = \lvert a - b\rvert$. It is also clearly monotonically increasing in $\lvert a - b\rvert$ since the map $$g(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}, \,\,\,\,\, x \ge 0$$ has derivative $$g'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{x}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} > 0$$ for all $x \ge 0$.